# Save accepted untrusted certificates on email app (HTC Sensation)

Tags: email, certificates, htc-sensation

I have a problem with the mail (not gmail) app on my HTC Sensation, that I'm guessing is part of HTC Sense 3. I'm using a server that has an untrusted certificate, and every time I try to refresh my email a dialog requesting the certificate to be accepted pops up. The problem is that when I try to send an email from that account the messages get stuck in the outbox until I manually refresh the mail forcing the certificate to be accepted again.

Is there any way of storing the known/already-accepted certificates for the mail app?

Thanks!

Comment: [Option 2](https://motorola-enterprise.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/57093/~/android---root-certificate-management) seems most promising.  And [another method](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~jimc/g1-htc/x509-root.shtml).

Comment: Did you check whether that would work with *server certificates*? In both cases, topic are *Certificate Authorities* (CAs) -- which are the ones who *sign* those server-certificates the OP has trouble with. Would be interesting to know whether one of the described methods is applyable here.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest switching to an alternative mail app -- [K-9 Mail](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fsck.k9) probably is a good choice. I use it for about 2 years now with a mail server having an "untrusted" (self-signed) certificate, and never experienced what you describe -- so this should solve your issue.